# Can we create a rich text email body for our "start and wait for an approval"

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, approval-process

We have this "Start and wait for an approval":

[image]

But I need to create custom email body, which will have tables, links and rich text. So is this possible? as in our case the Details field can only hold plain text and dynamic values, no rich text capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approval details supports rich formatting using **Markdown** syntax.

Using markdown syntax you can easily add tables, hyperlinks, ordered or numbered lists, bold, italics, headers, etc.

Check this documentation for more information, syntax and known limitations for different clients (outlook, teams, outlook web, etc.): [Use Markdown in Power Automate approval requests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/approvals-markdown-support)

Comment: this worked for me thanks